# PHP more elegant way to make random 1 or 0 binary pattern

Tags: php, random, binary

I am wondering if there is a more elegant way to create a random mix of 4 1's and 0's in PHP. The way I do it works but I am curious if there is a way to do the same thing with less code?

```
$b1 = rand(0,1);
$b2 = rand(0,1);
$b3 = rand(0,1);
$b4 = rand(0,1);

$randpattern = $b1.$b2.$b3.$b4;
```

Comment: `rand(0,15)` can represent each bit of a nibble (4 bit)

Comment: So would rand(128,255) represent every possible bit in a byte? Or (127, 256)? Thanks! I never realized you could do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Slightly shorter still:

```
$randpattern = substr(decbin(rand(16, 31)), -4);
```

The `rand(16,31)` will generate a random number between 16 and 31 which is made into a binary number, with `decbin()`, between 10000 en 11111. Finally the `substr()` picks only the last four characters.

Answer (score 4):

Sure:

```
str_pad(decbin(rand(0, 15)), 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

1. Call `rand()` only once. It will give a random number between 0 and 15. 15 in binary is 1111. You can also write 15 in binary to make it clear. `rand(0, 0b1111)`
2. Convert into binary.
3. If number is less than 1000 then left pad it with 0.

Comment: should be 0-15 actually.. otherwise, neat solution ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use a loop :

```
$randpattern = '' ;
while( strlen($randpattern) < 4 )
    $randpattern .= rand(0,1);
```